# Which class to implement variable padding of RecyclerView items?

Tags: android

I want to implement margins for the content of my vertically oriented `RecyclerView`.

The requirements are as follows:

- Items must be full-width so that the entire row has a background and is clickable.
- I can change the 'margin' size for the content in all items shown by the `RecyclerView`. So screen A and screen B can use the same `RecyclerView`, `Views` and `ViewHolder` classes but A and B can have different spacing to the left and right of their content.

I believe the requirements mean that I need to use padding (instead of margins) to achieve this effect. And I can think of 2 ways to implement this:

1. Set the view padding in `RecyclerView.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder` when the view is inflated.
2. Override the `LayoutManager.addView` method and set the padding there.

I am not sure whether this is the right approach and would value some advice! Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing padding using view.setPadding() after assigning views in the view holder class?

Comment: subclass ItemDecoration

Comment: @Blackbelt The reason I don't wan't to use `ItemDecoration` is that it creates a margin outside the view. This breaks my first requirement that the view items must be full width.

Comment: @LonelyCpp I did consider this but I didn't think it was really the `ViewHolder`s responsibility to be dealing with layout and formatting